# Script to run function at specific time with milliseconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have that code at below, how can I run it at 21:36:00:500 (500 is milliseconds) ?

```
var now = new Date();

var millisTill1 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 23, 45, 30, 500) - now;
if (millisTill1 < 0) {
     millisTill1 += 86400000;
}
setTimeout(function() {
  check()
}, millisTill1);
```

Comment: The lowest value available for `setTimeout` after HTML5 is 4ms. You can't have a timeout lower than that threshold.

Comment: Can you show me code with declare microseconds?

Comment: Do you want milliseconds or microseconds? Your timestamp "21:36:00:50" is 500 milliseconds (with the trailing 0 chopped off).

Comment: I want 500 milliseconds, sorry for wrong information

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Maybe the solution does not require this precision. For example. If the code 500ms late, how will it affect your code or experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this code for 1 minute timer execution it works. Also it just adds to the time limit after which it executes once. Kindly consider this code.

```js
tDate = new Date();
tDate.setHours(21);
tDate.setMinutes(36);
tDate.setSeconds(0);
tDate.setMilliseconds(500);

tMillis = tDate - new Date();

if (tMillis < 0)
  tMillis = tMillis + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // if time is greater than 21:36:00:500 just add 24 hours as it will execute next day 

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Execute');
}, tMillis)
```

You can validate the code by using 1 minute ahead timer to confirm the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with setTimeout. setTimeout function requires you to pass a second parameter (called millisTill1 in your example) in milliseconds.

Most browsers, have a bottom threshold of 10ms, which means you can't go below 10000 microseconds or 0.01s.

While JS is not suitable for this, most common task that would get you where you need to go would most probably use setInterval and look like:

```
(setInterval(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  if (
    currentTime.getHours() === 1 &&
    currentTime.getMinutes() === 38 &&
    currentTime.getSeconds() === 0 &&
    currentTime.getMilliseconds() === 500
  ) {
    // your code
  }
}, 500))();
```

This one would check the time each time a pollingTime interval passes. Most commonly this would be 1 minute (60000). You can go lower, but risk performance issues. Don't forget javascript runs on the client. If you would use setTimeout time would be checked only once and your script would stop.

If you need to execute something, better use a combination of system scheduler like Task Scheduler on Windows or Automator on OSX with a scripting language like bash or python.

Comment: I want 500 milliseconds, sorry for wrong information.

Comment: I got error at line 11: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: A fix it and now: Uncaught TypeError: setInterval(...) is not a function
    at <anonymous>:11:8

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to use this? This should work ok in the browser.

Comment: In the browser on site :(

Comment: By this approach it will keep on checking every half a second which is not a performance friendly option. @VlatkoVlahek

Comment: You cannot catch a 500ms interval change if you are not checking that often. There is no way to pass a callback to be triggered at an exact time.